# array reduce javascript typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reduce

Just for my own culture.
I have understood how works the reduce principle

```
var sumAll = function(...nums: number[]):void{
    var sum = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b , 0);

    document.write("sum: " + sum + "<br/>");
}
sumAll(1,2,3,4,5);
```

It gives 15 because we start at 0.

and 1+2= 3 first call -> 1+2 are replace by 3

3+3=6 second call 3 -> 3
+3 are replaced by 6

6+4 = 10 thrid call  -> 6+4 are replaced by 10

10+5 = 15 fourth call -> 10 + 5 are replaced by the final result 15

it's ok.

but what's happen when I do

```
var sumAll = function(...nums: number[]):void{
    var sum = nums.reduce((a, b, c) => a + b +c , 0);

    document.write("sum: " + sum + "<br/>");
}
sumAll(1,2,3,4,5);
```

the result is 25 but i don't understand why...
I guessed

first call: 1+2+3 = 6 (1+2+3 are replaced by 6)

second call 6+4+5 = 15 ( 6 +4 + 5 are replaced by 15 and it's the final result)

but why the result gives 25?

Thanks in advance;)

Comment: Did you read the docs? It'll tell you exactly why. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): The third argument passed to the callback is the index value of the current array element being processed.

Comment: follow this link - http://pythontutor.com/typescript.html#code=var%20sumAll%20%3D%20function%28...nums%3A%20number%5B%5D%29%3Avoid%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20sum%20%3D%20nums.reduce%28%28a,%20b,%20c%29%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2Bc%20,%200%29%3B%0A%0A%7D%0AsumAll%281,2,3,4,5%29%3B&curInstr=0&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=ts&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I have understood:)

Indeed my error was not to consider c as an index:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var sum = nums.reduce((a, b, c) => a + b +c , 0);` then `c` is *not a member of the numbers array. Its actually an *index*. Hence it is not reducing to the sum of the elements of the array.

## More

Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example